# converting date time format to default mysql format

Tags: php, mysql

I have this following date format as my input

```
Sat 15 June
```

Is it possible to convert to

```
2013-06-15
```

I have used explode functions and done it. But its a long procedure though.
I have also tried this:

```
date("Y-m-d",strtotime($input_date));
```

But this wont work properly...

Is there any direct function in PHP to convert into MySql date format ???
Or any built in function in php/ conversion function ????

Thanks in advance...

Comment: and where is the year in `Sat 15 June` !

Comment: PHP doesn't know which year to use. It was Sat 15 June back in 2002 as well, so try specifying the year.

Comment: No year is given as input, It must be the present year ....

Comment: Could you please define "not working properly"?  What unexpected results are you getting?

Comment: @user1954222 that's OK, then what's wrong with this code `echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime("Thu 2 May"));`

Comment: your code is working output 13-05-02 for 2013 use Y instead of y

Comment: @all until such time as the OP provides sufficient information to afford a proper answer it would be best practice *not* to "answer".  r̶e̶p̶e̶a̶t̶i̶n̶g̶   regurgitating the same code only serves to waste *everyones* time who read through questions and effectively constitutes spam.

Comment: @Lix sorry for taking your time for this orphan question/answer.

Answer (score -3):

This outputs `2013-06-15` at my end.

```
<?php
$input_date = "Sat 15 June";
$formatted_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($input_date));
echo $formatted_date;
?>
```

Note that there might be some confusion about the year, since `$input_date` doesn't contain a year. I think PHP will use the current year. Be careful.

Comment: This code is identical to the code the OP has given... How is this an answer?

Comment: @Lix Well, then the answer is that his code is fine. The problem might lie somewhere else. "Not working properly" isn't much of a problem description anyway.

Comment: `"The problem might lie somewhere else"` is **not** an answer.

Comment: @Lix Could you please explain how this code is wrong! I think down voting without describing the error is really bad.

Comment: I did describe what is wrong with your answer. There is nothing wrong with the code - as others have said - that code is correct. What's wrong with the answer is that "It works for me" is not a helpful answer. It would however, have been a helpful comment.

Comment: @Lix "Somehere else" as in a part of the code not shown in the question. Anyway, I see your point. But given the phrasing of the question, this is the only answer we can give, as shown by the other 2 answers.

Comment: I'm glad you can now see what I'm talking about and I hope that there are no hard feelings... My actions are not personal attacks on any users - I only consider the actual content of the posts and not the user who posted them at all...

Answer (score -3):

Check this one,

```
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime("Thu 2 May"));
```

> If you do not supply year in strtotime() function, it will take current year as the year value.

Comment: Same as the rest of these answers - you are simply posting the exact same code the OP is already using. No additional information or help is offered - you might have just copied the code from the question...

Comment: @Lix I've checked the code and it's working. Anyway how do you know it's a wrong answer?

Comment: @Lix "you might have just copied the code from the question...". so what? prove the answer is wrong. please don't ever down-vote someone before verifying the exact error in their code.

Comment: Your answer is not wrong - it is also not helpful as no additional information/explanations are given.."It works for me" is not a helpful answer. It would however, have been a helpful comment.

Comment: @Lix I think this much of additional explanation is enough for this **2 functions**.

Comment: You might think so - I do not. This is the reason for my downvote.

Comment: @Lix prob is the OP is not responding/explaining what error he is getting by using this code and before that one you just started to down-vote each and every one. Thanks

Comment: Prob is the OP not responding and *people answering anyway* instead of waiting for clarification.